# Recommended order of updating a database

Tags: database, updates

Granted that while updating a database, there are DELETED records, UPDATED records and INSERTED (new) records. What would be the recommended order for performing the updates?

I currently do DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT. My reason is as follows:

1. **DELETED** records are not in the DB anymore (at least from the user's point of view) so they should be removed first.
2. **UPDATED** records should go next because they are modifying existing data.
3. **INSERTED** records go last to fill the DB with the newest records.

Is this sequence satisfactory or a different order would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence is satisfactory you don't need to change.